# Error while running brew upgrade aws-sam-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, apple-m1

```
Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
    arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.
```

About the Mac

OS : macOS Monterey Version 12.6.5
Chip : Apple M1 Pro